# Laravel local scope intellisense

Tags: php, laravel, intellisense, magic-methods

i'm using local scope functions in laravel (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes)
Especially i'm using laravel_ide_helper 4.3.2 and laravel 5.3 (Updating is *not an option*)

Let's say i have a user class like that:

```php
class User extends Model {

    //other things here such as constructor ...

    public static function scopePopular($query)
    {
        return $query->Where('ispopular', true);
    }
}
```

Now lets say that i have a controller method where i do:

```php
public function GetPopularOnes(){
     return User::popular()->get();
}
```

Intellisense here works

Now take a look at this:

```php
public function GetPopularOnesSmall(){
     return User::select(['name', 'surname'])->popular()->get();
}
```

In this intellisense still works.

Again, look at this:

```php
public function GetPopularWomans(){
     return User::query()->where('gender', 'f')->popular();
}
```

In this intellisense **does not work**, but i'm sure that's right (or at least works).

So, my questions are:

- Is that working in newer versions of laravel/helper?
- Is there any known workaround?

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Intelligence sees a Builder instance being returned by "where", it doesn't know about the function defined on user

Comment: Exactly, the problem here is that builder is a class used by every eloquent model when building queries.
It would be really nice if Builder was a generic class, something like Builder<T> where in this case T is user.
In that case ide helper would have an handhold to generate right dock blocks.